# Ionic Slides: append a new slide with angular scope variables binding

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, swiper.js

Here is the plunker demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/7ROJ3l/?show=preview

I have this use case where I want to append a slide to Ionic slider dynamically after a particular promise gets resolved.

Appending a pure HTML text to the Slider is very simple. But when I try to bind `angular variables` from my controller using `{{ }}` , they don't get processed. Please refer the above [plunker demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/7ROJ3l/?show=preview) to understand what I mean. Is there any way I could append a slide and I could also use the controller scope variables?

As a work-around, I have tried `ng-repeat` instead of appending a new slide. Here is another Plunker showing that: http://embed.plnkr.co/CL9P4I/?show=preview

In this solution I think I have accidentally discovered a new bug. Here the second slide page do not properly follow the CSS styles that are mentioned there. after swiping the slider for the first time, it gets back to the normal behaviour. Have a look at the [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/CL9P4I/?show=preview) to get the clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Working Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/wKsaRJ?p=preview

You need to create an array or an object to pass through by `ng-repeat` with your data. Like:

```
$scope.mySlides = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
```

And use `ng-repeat` inside your `<ion-slide-page>`. Like:

```
<ion-slide-page ng-repeat="slide in mySlider">{{ slide }}</ion-slide-page>
```

Editing your Plunker I successfully made these changes and worked.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. This definitely works successfully. But as I mentioned in my Question, `$scope.mySlides` array must be updated after a promise resolves(for simplicity's sake, I have used $timeout).  Which causes slight distortion in the slides. It can be seen in this plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/CL9P4I/?show=preview